# PHP How to get hours and minutes of Date Time format '1:24 pm Tue 19 May'

Tags: php, date, datetime

How can I get the hours and minutes of '1:24 pm Tue 19 May'? Thanks

**My Test:**

```
<?php
$start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date_full));
$start_time = date("H:i a", strtotime($start_date_full));
echo $start_date . ', ' . $start_time;
```

**Output:**

> 2015-05-19, 00:00

Comment: split with pm or am and append at the end. And pass it into strtotime then it'll wotk

Comment: Check this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

```
 $d = '2015-05-19 13:24:00';
 $f = date('g:i a D d M', strtotime($d));
 echo $f;

 // OUTPUT : 1:24 pm Tue 19 May
```

Follow this - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think that's what you want

```
$date = date("g:i a l d F");
```

Output :

5:41 am Tuesday 19 May

Comment: `$start_date = date("h:i a D d M", strtotime($start_date_full) );`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$start_date_full = "1:24 pm Tue 19 May";
$format = "g:i a D j F";
$date_time = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $start_date_full);
echo date_format($date_time,"g:i");
```